# How do I get the minimum transaction amount with the binance api?

Tags: binance, binance-api-client, ccxt

How do I get the minimum transaction amount with the binance api?
For example, the minimum purchase price for MANA / USDT and ATOM / USDT is '10 USDT'.
The same is true for BTC / USDT.
How do I get it from'from binance.client import Client'?
I also want to know how to get it using ccxt.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Look for the `MIN_NOTIONAL` filter in the [exchangeInfo](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo) endpoint. It can have different value for each pair symbol.

Path `symbols[<index>].filters` contains an array of filters. One of them should always have `filterType` value `MIN_NOTIONAL`. The value in `minNotional` is the minimal order amount in the quote currency (in your case `USDT`).

Docs: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#filters